# open udp multicast video stream on android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-networking

How can I open a udp multicast video stream on android ?

I tried this code:

```
public class androidActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri video = Uri.parse("udp://224.1.1.1:1234");

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
}
```

}

but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's an old question, but have you found a good way to do that on Android?

Answer (score 1):

**Android doesnt support UDP for audio and video playback.**

see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: not natively, but some media players can open a udp video stream.

Comment: @jacob could you give me a link to any?

Comment: jacob, about the wording you just used... ironically, it's much easier to do it "natively" than using the Android VM.... Personally, I use FFMPEG and just open the UDP link in native code to pass the packets over directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RTP over UDP.
This is with RTSP setup via TCP.
I do this with stock android rom, no third party apps required.
Stagefright framework.

Comment: Do you have any sample app?